# anova on a sequence of models stored in a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, anova

I am running a series of models and storing them in a `list`:

```
fm0 <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  m <- formula(mpg ~ disp)
  if(i > 1)
    m <- update.formula(m, ~ . + gear)
  if(i > 2)
    m <- update.formula(m, ~ . + qsec)
  fm1 <- lm(m, data = mtcars)
  fm0[[i]] <- fm1
  names(fm0)[i] <- paste0("m",i)
}
```

I want to run `anova` on the sequence of models like this:

```
anova(fm0$m1, fm0$m2, fm0$m3)
# Analysis of Variance Table
# 
# Model 1: mpg ~ disp
# Model 2: mpg ~ disp + gear
# Model 3: mpg ~ disp + gear + qsec
#   Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
# 1     30 317.16                           
# 2     29 317.01  1    0.1443 0.0130 0.9099
# 3     28 309.83  1    7.1839 0.6492 0.4272
```

but I want something generic where I do not need to type out each named component of the list as the number of models is varying (depending on the data, which is set up in another loop, in which the loop above sits).

I tried `lapply(fm0, anova)`, but it runs `anova` on each model on its own, which is not what I am after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an absolutely inelegant solution:

```
eval(parse(text=paste("anova(",paste("fm0[[",1:length(fm0),"]]",sep="",collapse=","),")")))
```

Comment: Jeroen Ooms asked [the same question](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Anova-over-a-list-of-models-td893809.html) over at nabble back in 2009 and did not get a better answer, so I guess your answer is it.